# Error with HTMLParser module python

Tags: macos, python-2.7, html-parsing

Hi ok so I'm learning Python and going through a tutorial on Youtube. [youtube][https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V0UvE0Oun5Q] 
This is at 2hr06min. 
I'm not sure why I'm getting the TypeError saying three given arguments. 
Second question is why hasn't this a **init** method?
Thanks for any help.

```
import HTMLParser
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

# create a subclass and override the handler methods
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    #function to handle the processing if HTML comments
    def handle_comment(self, data):
        print "Encountered comment:", data
        pos = self.getpos()
        print "At line: ", pos[0], " position ", pos[1]

def main():
#instantiate the parser and feed it some HTML
    parser = MyHTMLParser()
    #open the HTML file in this dir and read it
    f = open("samplehtml.html")
    if f.mode == "r":
    contents = f.read() # read the entire file
    parser.feed(contents)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main();
```

The Error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "HTMLParser.py", line 5, in <module>
    import HTMLParser
File "/HTMLParser.py", line 10, in <module>
    class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Comment: Why not get rid of the first line? You have one import of the module and another of the class, but both with the same name, and that's not what the tutorial shows.

Comment: Yes that's true, I put it in because with out it I was getting                                                 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "HTMLParser.py", line 7, in <module>
         from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
       File "/HTMLParser.py", line 7, in <module>
           from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
       ImportError: cannot import name HTMLParser

Comment: Then you have a problem. Do you have another `HTMLParser` shadowing the one you want (is your file named `HTMLParser.py`, for example)?

Comment: AH thanks @jonrsharpe. That was what it was. Strangely enough the code worked fine in CentOS, But on Mac OS it didn't like having the same name as the imported module.